# Java Generate Arrays

Tags: swing

I'm working on a Java swing application that plots points. I'm using a third party graph plotting .jar which takes input from coordinates in a x array and a y array. Is there any way I can make the y array be a function of the x array? The function would be specified by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Define an interface XtoYFunction :

```
public interface XtoYFunction {
    int[] transform(int[] xCoordinates);
}
```

And let the user pass an implementation of this interface. Call its transform method with the X coordinates, and you'll get the corresponding Y coordinates.

If one Y depends on one X, the interface could be

```
public interface XtoYFunction {
    int transform(int xCoordinate);
}
```

You would simply loop through the X coordinates and call the function for each value to get its corresponding Y coordinate. For example:

```
plot(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
     new XtoYFunction() {
         @Override
         public int transform(int x) {
             return x * x;
         }
     });
```